# How to use something like assets:logoName in angular 2

Tags: css, angular, svg, angular-material

I am using angular 2 with cli tool to build something, I use angular material 2 for UI and also include Covalent Framework build on material.

In their teradata covalent framework, I want to build a top nav bar.

They have code like this:

```
<td-layout-nav logo="assets:teradata" toolbarTitle="Covalent" navigationRoute="/">
  Content goes here
</td-layout-nav>
```

I am not understanding the syntax here logo="assets:teradata", has someoen using this before? Looks like a SVG file, I don't know how to use the format like assets:

Answer (score 0):

Its to use the SVG from your assets folder usually assets/icons with name teradata.

you can read more about this on [covalent site](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/style-guide/product-icons).